# How to store data with N columns

Tags: sql

I need a way to store an int for N columns. Basically what I have is this:

```
Armies:
ArmyID  - UINT
UnitCount1 - UINT
UnitCount2 - UINT
UnitCount3 - UINT
UnitCount4 - UINT
...
```

I can't possible add a column for each and every unit, so I need a fast way to store the number of each units in an army (you might have guesses it's for a game by now). Using XML is not an option as it will be dead slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Armies
------
ArmyID


Units
-----
UnitID
Description
Strength
Hitpoints


ArmyUnits
---------
ArmyID
UnitID
Count
```

Comment: You should learn some about 3rd Normal Form http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form for databases. This solytion is exactly the 3NF for Your data. You should make all Your tables this way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use table like this:

```
Armies
(
  ArmyID
  UnitID
  UnitCount
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an 1:n relationship (3rd normal form)

```
Table Armies
  ArmyID

Table Units
  ArmyId
  UnitId
  UnitCount
```

Or do it in one table

```
Table ArmyUnits
  ArmyId 
  UnitId
  UnitCount
```

This obviously means that you have more than one entry per ArmyId.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two tables:

```
Armies:
ArmyID - UINT

Units:
ArmyID - UINT
UnitIndex - UINT
UnitCount - UINT
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to store your counts in a one to many relationship. With the UnitID in UnitCount table being a foreign key to the Armies table.

```
Armies
(
  ArmyID
  UnitID
)

UnitCount
(
  UnitID
  UnitCount
)
```